# javascript on with namespacing events

Tags: javascript, jquery

there is a weird behavior that when I use namespace event that the handler will always get fired.

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<span id="span1">click</span>
<span id="span2">click</span>


$("#div1").on("click.me", function(event, data){
     $(this).append(data.from);
});

$("#span1").on("click", function(event){
     $("div").trigger("click.me", [{from:"span1"}]);
});

$("#span2").on("click", function(event){
     $("div").trigger("click", [{from:"span2"}]);
});
```

so the div will append the data when I clicked on both span1 and span2. why is that ? didn't I only added the handler specific to "click.me" ?

I have it on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cY5sk/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Didn't I only added the handler specific to "click.me" ?

No, that's not how namespaces work. The handler is still bound to the particular event, but the namespace gives you an additional way to refer to them. It doesn't matter which namespace a handler belongs to, if the event is triggered, all handlers for that event are called, regardless which namespace the belong to.

Consider:

```
$("#div1").on("click.me", function(event, data){
     $(this).append(data.from);
});

$("#div1").on("click", function(event, data){
     $(this).append(data.from);
});
```

`$('div').trigger('click.me')` would only trigger the first handler, because you specified the `me` namespace. However, `$('div').trigger('click')` will trigger both handlers regardless of their namespace.

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> An event name can be qualified by event namespaces that simplify removing or triggering the event. For example, `"click.myPlugin.simple"` defines both the myPlugin and simple namespaces for this particular click event.

---

It seems like you are looking for *custom events*, e.g.

```
$("#div1").on("foo", function(event, data){
     $(this).append(data.from);
});

$("#span1").on("click", function(event){
     $("div").trigger("foo", [{from:"span1"}]);
});

$("#span2").on("click", function(event){
     $("div").trigger("click", [{from:"span2"}]);
});
```

Comment: what do you mean all handlers ? isn't "click.me" just overall one event ?

Comment: I mean that if a `click` events occurs, all event handlers that are bound to that event are called, no matter which namespace they belong to. Of course you only have one handler in your example, but I'm generalizing. E.g. if you had `$e1.on('click', ...)` and `e1.on('click.foo', ...)`, then both handlers are triggered when the click event is triggered.

Comment: What's with the downvotes? If someone thinks something is wrong with my answer, please let me know.

Comment: For other namespace for example "try.me" without the "click" prefix...if i do something.off(".me") does the "try" namespace still there ?

Comment: @user1389813: In this case `try` would be an event as well. And if you use `on` with a namespace only, it will remove all event handlers belonging to that namespace.

Comment: I think the downvote is from someone who doesn't understand how event namespaces work. This is unfortunate because you clearly site the documentation.